# Text alignment in gmail and yahoo

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

I have created one template. While opening in gmail account some of the text line is coming in center (basically Thank You Part) but when I am opening the same template in Yahoo it (Thank You Part) is properly left aligned. I did some analysis and came to know that it also depends upon the rendering of different mail client. I want to fix this issue. Could anyone please help me with that?

Comment: Could do with the html to assist you.

Comment: are you used align:left; and style="text-align:left" in your code

Comment: use above styles to the thank you part div

Comment: Actually for desktop it is coming properly for both gmail and yahoo.I am opening this template in mobile.For mobile I am not able to see what css property is getting reflected.

Comment: please add your code(template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mail clients have text:center as default, e.g. Gmail and Outlook 2007,2010,2013. So you need to specify in each `<td>` the alignment of the text, as well as all other inline styles.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td align="left" style="color:#000000">
    Lorem ipsum
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">
            Your Thank You text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```